# How do I use `pd.NamedAgg` with a lambda function inside a `pandas` aggregation?

Tags: pandas

I want to be able to feed a list as parameters to generate different aggregate functions in `pandas`. To make this more concrete, let's say I have this as data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': np.repeat(['x', 'y'], 10),
    'val': np.random.randint(0, 10, 20)
})
```

So the first few rows of the data looks like this:

| group | val |
| --- | --- |
| x | 5 |
| x | 0 |
| x | 3 |

I have a list of per-group percentiles that I want to compute.

```
percentile_list = [10, 90]
```

And I tried to use dictionary comprehension with `pd.NamedAgg` that calls a lambda function to do this.

```
df_agg = df_data.groupby('group').agg(
    **{f'p{y}_by_dict': pd.NamedAgg('val', lambda x: np.quantile(x, y / 100)) for y in percentile_list},
)
```

But it doesn't work. Here I calculate both by hand and by dictionary comprehension.

```
df_agg = df_data.groupby('group').agg(
    p10_by_hand=pd.NamedAgg('val', lambda x: np.quantile(x, 0.1)),
    p90_by_hand=pd.NamedAgg('val', lambda x: np.quantile(x, 0.9)),
    **{f'p{y}_by_dict': pd.NamedAgg('val', lambda x: np.quantile(x, y / 100)) for y in percentile_list},
)
```

The result looks like this. The manually specified aggregations work but the dictionary comprehension ones have the same values across different aggregations. I guess they just took the last lambda function in the generated dictionary.

|  | p10_by_hand | p90_by_hand | p10_by_dict | p90_by_dict |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1.8 | 7.2 | 7.2 | 7.2 |
| y | 1.0 | 8.0 | 8.0 | 8.0 |

How do I fix this? I don't have to use dictionary comprehension, as long as each aggregation can be specified programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
In [23]: def agg_gen(y):
    ...:     return lambda x: np.quantile(x, y / 100)
    ...:

In [24]:  df_data.groupby('group').agg(
    ...:     **{f'p{y}_by_dict': pd.NamedAgg('val', agg_gen(y)) for y in percentile_list},
    ...: )
Out[24]:
       p10_by_dict  p90_by_dict
group
x              1.8          7.2
y              1.0          8.0
```

the reason your initial assign fails is because of this - [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)